How to completely turn off the second screen on a ZenBook UX482 running Ubuntu?
I own a ZenBook UX482, which has a second screen. On Windows, there is a dedicated button to turn off, put to sleep, and turn on this second screen. However, after switching to Ubuntu (version 24.04), this button no longer works.
To work around this, I have tried creating a script using xrandr to control the state of the second screen. So far, I have managed to put the screen to sleep and turn it back on, but I cannot completely turn it off.
Here's what I've tried:
1. Putting the second screen to sleep:
xrandr --output [second_screen_name] --off

2. Turning the second screen back on:
xrandr --output [second_screen_name] --auto

However, when I try to completely turn off the second screen with the above command, it just goes to sleep and does not turn off entirely.
Do you have any suggestions on how I could completely turn off the second screen? Is there a specific command I could use or an alternative method to achieve this?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Are you sure you need to? Is there any practical difference between sleep and off here?

Yes, it's important because even in sleep mode, the screen still uses battery power since it's backlit. Additionally, if I accidentally touch the screen while it's in sleep mode, it moves my cursor, which can be quite disruptive. Being able to completely turn off the screen would help conserve battery and avoid these interruptions.

Fair enough, but battery? Isn't this an external screen?

Actually, my laptop is a ZenBook UX482, which is a dual-screen laptop with both screens integrated into the device. Since both screens are powered by the same internal battery, managing the power consumption of the second screen is important to maximize battery life.
